# How much energy is stored in a AA battery when its voltage has dropped to 1.2V?

Tags: voltage, batteries, boost, joule-thief

[image]

The general question is how useful it is to use weak batteries with a boost converter - say, boosting 3AA of 1V each to 5V?

According to this image it seems that only 5% of the energy is left when the voltage has dropped to 1.1V but about 50% when it's 1.2V and dead for most uses. Still this usefulness of boosting depends on its efficiency.

Is there a rule of thumb when boosting is advisable based on battery type, the remaining voltage and the required current?

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question. Was there anything else?

Comment: Dave is right. What are you really trying to ask?

Comment: How sensitive is the load to supply voltage? Does it still function as it should when the cells have dropped to 1.1V? If so there's no point in suffering the efficiency penalty of the converter.

Comment: Where did you get that graph? Can you include a link? I'd like to see more on that.

Comment: Here's the link: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/AA_Alkaline_battery_energy_usage_-_discharge_current_100mA.svg/725px-AA_Alkaline_battery_energy_usage_-_discharge_current_100mA.svg.png

Comment: Does rather depend on the AA battery. For a NiCd, that's almost fully charged.

Comment: @OMGsh - That link hasn't worked since you posted it. It just says the site it down for maintenance. It looks like a link to the image, do you have a link form the page it's from? Thanks.

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:AA_Alkaline_battery_energy_usage_-_discharge_current_100mA.svg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is hard to answer your exact question, since you want information on a scenario that has no commercial relevance, so companies are not going to test almost drained batteries just to know how much energy can be harvested from them.

Those discharge curves that they publish are used to design battery-powered products: the curves allow them to estimate how long *a completely new battery* can make the product work before the "low-battery" signal kicks-in.

Although your question has no commercial/industrial relevance, it could have some environmental relevance: if your intent is to reuse almost dead batteries in lower power devices, yours is a good question, but a difficult to answer one.

There is no easy answer. A drained alkaline battery cannot be characterized only by its voltage and internal resistance. Its past discharge history can have some impact on the residual energy content, and so does its exact chemistry and internal construction, which depend on the manufacturer.

For what is worth, if you have some environmentalist concerns, you could do something like what I do -- I try to completely drain old batteries: when the new ones are drained, I measure their voltage and if it is above 1.1V (for single cells) I keep those for low power devices, such as kitchen timers/clocks, wireless computer mice or the like.

When they are too weak to work for these low power devices, I reuse them in a [Joule thief](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief) circuit powering an LED as a night light. Joule thieves are quite inefficient step-up converters, but they can be powered using cells with about 0.7V terminal voltage, and once powered, they can drain the battery until it reaches something like 0.2V-0.3V (YMMV - it depends on the actual circuit).

Comment: Some things to keep in mind. 1. As batteries decrease in voltage, they are more likely to leak or corrode, so don't use a "dead" battery in an expensive or treasured device. By trying to save the environment, you actually can accidentally produce more landfill. 2. As used in a Joule Thief, you can extend the life of the night light by using a  10K to 50K potentiometer in addition to the usual 1K Joule-Thief resistor. In addition, putting a small ceramic capacitor in parallel with the sense winding resistance can also improve efficiency and brightness.

Answer (score 3):

Generally using a nearly-flat AA/AAA battery with a boost converter is not going to give you much, *especially* if the thing you're powering requires substantial power.
When the battery goes down, not only its voltage decreases, it's internal resistance increases as well, sometimes dramatically. So the battery may show, say, 1.1V when measured with a multimeter (and almost no current is drawn from the battery), but can quickly collapse to less than 1.0V when under 200 mA load:

[image: battery discharge graph]

(Source: [Battery university](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/choices_of_primary_batteries))

Answer (score 2):

Based strictly on the graph you provided:

The curve intersects 1.2V at about 16 hours, by my reading, and hits zero at about 25.5 hours. That's about 63% of the lifetime, or 63% of the coulombs. Without trying to calculate area under the curve exactly, we can observe that it's monotone decreasing, and therefore the joules available before 1.2V are *more than 63%* of the total. My eyeball says it's probably about 75%. Call it nitpicking, but this is a significant difference from "about 50%".

But as others have said, the real problem with using a boost converter on a battery, if your load needs any significant power, isn't necessarily efficiency. Your graph is for a constant-current discharge, but the lower the battery voltage gets, the more current the booster will need to draw from it to provide a constant power. The more current the booster draws, the further the battery voltage drops.  For any given power level, there is a point beyond which the battery won't deliver that much power at *any* voltage (consider the maximum power transfer theorem with the battery's internal resistance as the source resistance), and even a 100% efficient boost converter will be no help. And being imprecise, that point is really not very far past the 1.2V point, so your ability to work miracles is strictly limited.